# Why do companies prefer to employ younger people

Tags: job-search, job-description, employment

When I scour the job adverts I notice that companies favour employing young people (under 30). This is evident in the way they proudly state the young average age of their workforce (at the same time proudly saying that they don't discriminate on race or sex). I am sure that the young people look great as a group smiling on the company's website pictures, but do younger people offer more advantages for employers than employee's over 30 years old? If I think of the older people that I have have worked with they are knowledgeable, helpful and work reliably and consistently.

So my question is: Why is ageism still evident in the workplace when racism and sexism have largely been removed?

Comment: Young people do work longer for less. Young people are less prone to have families at home that they must take care of. Also, if upper management or hiring managers are young, they may feel awkward at having subordinates older than they are. That being said, I agree with you. One problem is that people tend to hire others that are similar to them in culture, race, age, etc.

Comment: Voting to close because the only currently possible answers are going to be filled with guesses based on unsubstantiated claims.  If you want a reliable answer, you'll have to ask the companies you see favoring those younger employees.

Comment: Hey, let's vote to close ALL the questions!  @Notme  Agism is a very real thing we encounter and I've outlined a few things below.  There are also steps you can take to counter it, but I guess it will become relevant when some of you are over 30

Comment: Voting to reopen

Comment: @RichardU: I'm way over 30.  However that doesn't change the fact that there are a plethora of reasons to want people of a certain age (young or old) for a given type of position.  This question states a belief by the OP that it's a new trend (it's not), asks for the science behind it (beyond scope of this site), and asks if the managers will fire everyone (depends on the company, relevant country laws governing it, the manager in question, etc).  In other words, it is unanswerable

Comment: @NotMe  A plethora?  Really?  Care to share the first five hundred?  Just because you can't think of an answer doesn't mean it's unanswerable.  In IT and engineering, this has been a problem for decades and there are very clear reasons why 30+ and especially 40+ are discriminated against.  IF y'all didn't kill the question within a half hour, you might have learned something.

Comment: @NotMe its really not feasible to do a survey of companies, I imagine well over half the questions on Stack Exchange could be answered with go off and do a survey/research. What would happen to stack exchange then? the only people using it would be the moderators. In terms of your arguments "plethora of reasons" "statements unproven", sorry just ridiculous, Stack Exchange is not a scientific journal.

Comment: There are types of development jobs where age is not as discriminated against. They are not in start-ups or the US West Coast Tech centers however. Look at government contracts, government positions and large enterprise type jobs in multinational corporations and you will find more older workers.

Comment: Employers are not supposed to discriminate, but I imagine the practice is very common in order to save a buck.

Comment: But you might find that image concious managers are following the West coast lead as it becomes the norm. An interesting question is why it is not being recognised as discrimination, maybe a pressure group is needed to bring the issue into conciousness before we all end up on the scrap heap.

Comment: I think its not that older employee's are expensive its just that younger employee's are cheap having just left school with no experience and with no dependants to support. If you are cheap then I suppose its a no brainer, the thing is that cheapness is inversely proportional to greatness.

Comment: @NotMe "the only currently possible answers are going to be filled with guesses based on unsubstantiated claims" - this is not necessarily true, there could have been studies into this issue since it is important to the health of our society (unless, like Margret Thatcher, you believe that only 'the market' and not society exists).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Agism, especially in IT is alive and well.

Employers have plenty of perceptions about older employees.

> Set in his ways:  An older employee is not going to embrace change.

"Embracing change" is one of the buzzwords of the day, and many employers think that only young people can do it.

> Too expensive:  An older, experienced employee is going to want to be paid more

This is actually true, but the employers tend to ignore the fact that an older employee is also going to bring in tricks that have been forgotten over the years and some that are not even taught any more.

> Tendency to get sick/higher medical costs.

Perhaps, but we're also less likely to go out partying and showing up hung over.

> What happens when everyone turns 30?

The perception is that they'll have already moved on, or gone into management or changed careers and will be replaced with a new crop of youngsters.

Comment: I think it is crazy to force a highly skilled technical person into management because of a vacuous management concept that they should have a young team or that engineers should progress to management. In doing this they must give up all their hard won engineering skills and knowledge and swap instead them for a diary and a smart suit (just what the economy needs more talkers!).

Comment: @ejectamenta It's very common.  By age 30 you should at least be a team-lead in IT.  In other industries, especially physically demanding ones or in union shops, it's expected that you move up or move out.

Comment: The higher value given to political ability (networking) over technical skills is unfortunate and reflects the shallowness of the world we currently live it.

Comment: @Richard, that is BS. I know plenty of programmers in their 40s, 50s and 60s who neither want to be team leads or manager or have accepted such positions.

Comment: I woudl also submit that thinking older workers are more expensive is often also not true especially if they have stayed in one place for more than 2-3 years. I have seen plenty of times when new employees with far less experience are hired for more because that is the current market price. Older workers have 10-20-30 years of 2-3% pay raises when the young are often starting at higher salaries than the older ones currently get.

Comment: @HLGEM they may not want to be managers, but they find it increasingly difficult to get engineering jobs because of the youth bias. The thing with the salary level is all assumptions on the part of the employer, I think that older applicants would be satisfied to be paid the market rate. However maybe they can force the salary level downwards by hiring someone fresh who is used to intern money, and that is another matter.

Comment: @HLGEM, yes, since you've seen something it must be universally true.  What is the definition of "plenty" again?

Comment: @RichardU And because you haven't seen it it must be universally false?

Comment: Maybe the whole ageism question can be answered "because of the stupidity of managers who value fashion and cheapness above wisdom, experience and skills"

Comment: While this entire comment section will be removed soon because this isn't a chat room, I just want to say that I'm a 49 year old software engineer and I have no problem finding work and I'm not a lead nor do I ever want to be a manager (again).  I've found Ageism to be nonexistent and I work with people of all ages.

Comment: Google is your friend.  Here's a quick search on that thing thad does not exist: => https://www.google.com/search?q=agism+in+it&amp;rls=com.microsoft:en-US&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;startIndex=&amp;startPage=1&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I was offering my personal experience. Note the phrase "I've found". Your snark is not constructive.

Comment: I'm cantankerous, not snarky.

Comment: Ageism is alive and well, personally I prefer them young or old, not in between. Younger people are more malleable/trainable/cheaper, older people such as myself have experience you can't buy. But that's just a preference, I'll go with anyone competent.